# Zentyal 3.3 to 5.1 upgrade. Cannot access samba shares from windows

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba, ubuntu-14.04, zentyal

**We recently upgraded our Zentyal 3.3 server to 5.1**
It was an upgrade process via software updates menu.
**The samba version were 4.1.3 and now it's 4.6.7**

After the upgrade I noticed that nobody can access the samba shares from windows.
It has a DC role, but also many file shares are configured fro the end users.
The sysvol share is working fine, users are able to authenticate, GPO are working too but the shares isn't. The error message is access denied.
**The only way to access them is if I set the "admin users" in smb.conf to the desire group or user**. But this bring me a new problem, because every user will be able to access every folder, even if they don't have access to is.

Finally I found a new "solution":
**If I set an AD user to access the share, then it's working correctly. But if I set an AD group, then it's failing.**
The AD groups are existing, and i verified that with several commands. The group memberships are also correct, so i can see perfectly that I'm member of those groups.

**Another thing, which may or my not be important:** 
The folder where the users write is mounted through iSCSI to another folder, then hard linket to /home directory. Previously it the data was directly there, but through the Zentyal upgrade process, we moved the data elsewhere (500 GB)

I searched for solution for over a day, but so far no luck.
According to the samba.log when I trying to access the shares, and using group permissions:

> [2018/11/02 20:22:57.348766, 3, pid=2560, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)]
>   ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp) string_to_sid:
>   SID @Domain Users is not in a valid format
>
> [2018/11/02 23:23:55.424532,  3]
>   ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)   chdir
>   (/home/samba/shares/iktato_uj) failed, reason: Permission denied
>   [2018/11/02 23:23:55.424574,  3]
>   ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
>   smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1]
>   status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at
>   ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449 [2018/11/02 23:23:55.427243,  3]
>   ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)   chdir
>   (/home/samba/shares/iktato_uj) failed, reason: Permission denied

**An example from shares.conf to a share that i'm trying to acccess:**

```
[Iktato_uj]
    comment = Iktato_uj
    path = /home/samba/shares/iktato_uj
    browseable = yes
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 0660
    valid users = @"Iktato", "molehand"
    read list =
    write list = @"Iktato", "molehand"
    admin users =
    vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
    full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open  rename
```

**Here is the output from samba-tool testparm**

```
# Global parameters [global]
        bind interfaces only = Yes
        interfaces = lo ens36
        netbios name = GAMESZSRV2
        realm = BVDOM.LOCAL
        server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbindd, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
        server string = Zentyal Server
        workgroup = BVDOM
        log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
        log level = 3
        max log size = 100000
        map to guest = Bad User
        server role = active directory domain controller
        server signing = if_required
        template homedir = /home/%U
        template shell = /bin/bash
        winbind enum groups = Yes
        winbind enum users = Yes
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
        drs:max object sync = 1200
        dsdb:schema update allowed = yes
        server role check:inhibit = yes
        comment =
        include = /etc/samba/shares.conf

[homes]
        comment = Saját könyvtárak
        path = /home/%S
        browseable = No
        create mask = 0611
        directory mask = 0711
        read only = No
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename
        full_audit:success = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Vendeg]
        comment = Vendeg
        path = /home/samba/shares/vendeg
        admin users = "@All domain users" "@Domain Admins"
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = "@All domain users" "@Domain Admins" "@All domain users" "@Domain Admins"
        write list = "@All domain users" "@Domain Admins"
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[muszak]
        comment = Muszak
        path = /home/samba/shares/muszak
        admin users = @Muszak
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @Muszak @Muszak
        write list = @Muszak
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Vezetes]
        comment = Vezetés
        path = /home/samba/shares/vezetes
        admin users = @Vezetes
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @Vezetes @Vezetes
        write list = @Vezetes
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Domain users]
        comment = Domain users
        path = /home/samba/shares/users
        admin users = "@Domain Userek"
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = "@Domain Userek" "@Domain Userek"
        write list = "@Domain Userek"
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Berlemeny]
        comment = Bérlemény
        path = /home/samba/shares/berlemeny
        admin users = @Berlemeny
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @Berlemeny @Berlemeny
        write list = @Berlemeny
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Szamvitel]
        comment = Számvitel
        path = /home/samba/shares/szamvitel
        admin users = @Szamvitel
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @Szamvitel @Szamvitel
        write list = @Szamvitel
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Iktato]
        comment = Iktató
        path = /home/samba/shares/iktato
        admin users = @Iktato
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @Iktato @Iktato
        write list = @Iktato
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[HR]
        comment = HR
        path = /home/samba/shares/hr
        admin users = @hr1
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @hr1 @hr1
        write list = @hr1
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[intezmenyi]
        comment = intézmények abevjava
        path = /home/samba/shares/intezmenyi
        admin users = @anyk
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @anyk @anyk
        write list = @anyk
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Próba]
        comment = teszt
        path = /home/samba/shares/proba
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[Iktato_uj]
        comment = Iktato_uj
        path = /home/samba/shares/iktato_uj
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 0660
        valid users = @Iktato molehand
        write list = @Iktato molehand
        vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
        full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/bvdom.local/scripts
        browseable = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No
```

**smb.conf output**

```
[global]
    workgroup = bvdom
    realm = BVDOM.LOCAL
    netbios name = gameszsrv2
    server string = Zentyal Server
    server role = dc
    server role check:inhibit = yes
    server services = -dns
    server signing = auto
    dsdb:schema update allowed = yes
    ldap server require strong auth = no
    drs:max object sync = 1200

    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%U

    interfaces = lo,ens36
    bind interfaces only = yes

    map to guest = Bad User

    log level = 3
    log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
    max log size = 100000


    include = /etc/samba/shares.conf

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/bvdom.local/scripts
    browseable = no
    read only = yes

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = no
```

I also tried a few methods with unix permissions, stb, but no luck. 
It seems to me that it's not able to recognize the AD groups, when i want to use them to access shares.

**So to summarize:**

**User ACL are working, group doesn't**

**UPDATE: I tried to create a new share to another folder then the mounted iscsi and smb access worked perfectly. So I checked again the unix permissions and modified one from the iscsi mount. After I modified the acl and made myself the owner of a folder I was able to access it from the network and modify the ACL from windows. So it seems like it's a simple file system permission problem, nothing more. I hope i can make it work for the other shares too**

I appreciate any solution or tip.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The update probably broke the group mapping for the "Domain Users" group. It happened for us as well. Have a look at this answer for a solution: https://superuser.com/a/1310572/704830